# How can I tell WKWebView what layout width to use?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have some `html` content stored in `NSData` that I want to display with WKWebView. Think of it as `ASCII` art essentially. The problem I'm having is that WKWebView insists on laying out the content in such a way that it will fit the width of the device at 1.0 scale. So it wraps lots of lines of text, making it look bad.  For better or worse the `HTML` content was generated with the intent that line breaks would only happen at explicit `<br>` instances, and I can't really change that.  What I would like is to be able to tell WKWebView "Lay this page out as if the screen is 1000px wide, even if it isn't", and then the user can horizontally scroll to see the longer lines if needed, or zoom out until the long lines fit.

**I've tried many things but haven't been able to get anything to work.**

- I tried mucking with the WKWebView's `frame` and `contentSize`. *(no effect)*
- I tried changing the WKWebView's UIScrollView's `frame` and `contentSize`. *(no effect)*
- I tried adding user scripts with `[config.userContentController addUserScript:script]`. *(didn't seem to actually invoke these at all when using `loadData` or `loadHTMLString`. Maybe they only work with loading via URL?)*
- Tried adding a preamble to the html string itself of `<meta name='viewport' content='width=2000'>` *(That made the view horizontally scrollable out to 2000 pixels, but the html content still wrapped at device width)*
- Tried putting the WKWebView inside a separate UIScrollView with `frame` and `contentSize` set wider than the screen. *(no effect)*

I'm ok with a solution that requires appending or prepending something onto the HTML itself, but I'd prefer not to have to make CSS modifications that make assumptions about the content of the document. So things like the viewport meta are fine, but adding special CSS overrides for particular element tags is not so great (e.g. making all the `span` elements be `display: inline-block;`).  Best would be if there were a way in the iOS APIs themselves to cajole WKWebView into doing layout into wider bounds than the screen.

The setup is pretty plain.  I've got a `MyUIViewController` and it has essentially this code to make the WKWebView and load the data.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
  _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame configuration:config];
  [self.view addSubview:_webView];
  [_webView loadData:_data
                   MIMEType:@"text/html"
      characterEncodingName:@"UTF-8"
                    baseURL:_baseURL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the (easiest) way to solve this would be on the HTML side but from your description I am not sure that is possible. You say think of it as ASCII art but also not to make CSS changes that make assumptions about the document, so it is not entirely clear.

If you embed what you display into some tag like `code` or `pre` (easiest) or get the CSS to break it the way you want (less easy) I think it will solve your problem.

So why not put what you want to display into `pre`?

Answer (score 0):

there a lot different ways to come closer to a nicely looking visual.

#### A - userAgent

your webview pretends to be a desktop browser (**UserAgent**) and so the css rules for that one are in charge rather than those for mobile devices. You could use the following code below to change the UserAgent. But this solution is inconvenient because it fixes your webview to be used with css @media formatting that is not meant to be seen with smaller screens. The opposite problem of yours would pop up, pages zoomed so small that they cant barely be used properly depending on your devices.

```
[self.webView setCustomUserAgent:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4"];
```

or same idea but different way, you set your

```
WKWebViewConfiguration::defaultWebpagePreferences: //to another

WKContentMode::preferredContentMode = WKContentModeDesktop;
```

(did not test it, if this would help much and solve it once and for all)

but you could also overrule the authors scale settings when

```
WKWebViewConfiguration::(BOOL)ignoresViewportScaleLimits = YES
```

#### B - tree parsing

complicated solution, you hook up into the **html tree** and kick out the `<br>` in the html-tagged boxes yourself. You end up programming/using a **xml parser** from which are plenty of existing out there, even inside iOS there are at least 3 different ready made frameworks. Bare understanding of which one is the best for your scenario is eating up your time. Worth mentioning that HTML is actually `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` which is `NSAttributedStringDocumentType` which is `NSAttributedString` and so also just a `NSString` where you could

```
NSAttributedString *document = //your document
[document stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br>" withString:@""];
```

(Trouble with this is you probably don't want to parse out all `<br>`)

#### D - inject js or css

as you mentioned yourself, you could try to inject a **css** or **js** which is overruling the layout problems. Also complicated and does not work for all possible content because it is too specific to this particular webpage. And a weak solution also because the webpage could change (if its not yours anyway) and all have to be done again because it breaks. But your starting point to do so would be

```
userContentController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString* scriptLocation = [bundle pathForResource:@"webscreen" ofType:@"js"];
NSString* scriptSource = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:scriptLocation encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
WKUserScript* userScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptSource injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart forMainFrameOnly:YES];
[userContentController addUserScript:userScript];
[userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:(id<WKScriptMessageHandler>)self name:@"webscreen"];
config.userContentController = userContentController;
```

#### E - resizeSubviews (macOS only)

You resize UIView with (which is NOT available on iOS) `[self resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:NSZeroSize];` but i think you can still use CGAffineTransform on your content in another way. This is how it would look like on macOS. something like..

```
- (void)resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:(NSSize)oldSize
{
    CGRect bounds = NSRectToCGRect(self.bounds);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 2.0, 2.0);
    CGRect childBounds = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(bounds, transform);
    _webView.frame = childBounds;
}
```

#### F - move WKWebView into a UIScrollView

possibly the fastest way to have some control over the width of your webpage while  making a part of it available to the user. *Moving* the whole *implementation* of your `WKWebView` into an `UIScrollView` and placing this instead of the "old" webview in your ViewController. The downside is, this can conflict with the websites zoom and native scrolling behaviour of the HTML document. You will have to know when to catch where, which UIEvents. But you could also tell this new UIScrollView to be fixed if needed. The WebViews frame can then be larger than the visible Rect of your Device.

Hope there are some ideas for ya. Would like to know what is your solution at the very end. Cheers